# Get input string from user and store it into string array

Tags: java

Can someone please help me to solve this? I want to store input from user which is a string into string array. Error is: `Java.lang,String connot be converted into string.String`

Here is my code:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int nSize;
System.out.println("Enter size of array to store data..:");
nSize = input.nextInt();

String[] names= new String[nSize]; // name array
int[] phone= new int[nSize]; //phone array
for ( int i = 1; i <= nSize;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name..:");
    names[i] = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter phone number.:");
    phone[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Well, don't name your class `String` when you don't want it to be confused with a different class also named `String`.

Comment: please post your full class.

Comment: Also if you are storing phone number in int array it cannot store 10 digit number. If you want to store phone numbers as number you need to use long.

Comment: Do you want to store each character in the string in individual indexes of the string array?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I really appreciate it

Comment: Error while taking full name from user as well as on phone "InputMismatchErro"

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and did not encounter the issue that you have described in your question.

I did, however, find an issue with the same line, which is likely the solution to your problem. (A mismatch error)

You should use `names[i] = input.next();`  instead of `names[i] = input.nextLine();` Otherwise, it will return an empty string.

Comment: i am facing problem. when i entered a name and press enter it throw an error " Input mismatch error"

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nSize;
        System.out.println("Enter size of array to store data..:");
        nSize = input.nextInt();
        String[] names = new String[nSize]; // name array
        int[] phone = new int[nSize]; //phone array
        for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name..:");
            names[i] = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter phone number..:");
            phone[i] = input.nextInt()`enter code here`;
        }
```

Comment: Hello @naeem khan, try with the above solution. it's working fine. In your code, you are storing values at 1st index but you should store in 0 indexes. Observe 'for' loop initialization.

Comment: its not working. When i put full name like "naeem khan" , it gives error and same is the case for number

Answer (score 0):

After executing your code, I didn't see the error you have mentioned. Also, the desired output is a bit ambiguous. 
However, I tried to implement what I interpreted from it by using *BufferedReader* like,

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int nSize;
    System.out.println("Enter size of array to store data..:");
    try {
        nSize = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String[] names = new String[nSize]; // name array
        long[] phone = new long[nSize]; // phone array
        for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name..:");
            names[i] = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter phone number.:");
            phone[i] = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());

        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Check if it helps.